# SQL query very slow within Symfony, but very fast in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Business Intelligence App. I'm running the following query within a Symfony Repository :

```
public function countSubscribers()
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id))
    FROM account a
    INNER JOIN customer c ON c.account = a.id
    INNER JOIN payment p ON p.customer = c.id
    WHERE p.init != 1
    AND p.cancel_date IS NULL
    AND p.unpaid != 1
    AND p.abo = 1
    AND p.value != 0
    AND c.date_next_payement > NOW()";

    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchColumn();

    return $result;
}
```

The page is very slow to load, and according to the symfony profiler, the query took more than 15 seconds to execute :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id)) FROM account a INNER JOIN customer c ON c.account = a.id INNER JOIN payment p ON p.customer = c.id WHERE p.init != 1 AND p.cancel_date IS NULL AND p.unpaid != 1 AND p.abo = 1 AND p.value != 0 AND c.date_next_payement > NOW() Parameters: { }
[Hide runnable query]
Time: 14553.83 ms [ - Explain query ]
Explanation:
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  c   ALL     PRIMARY,UNIQ_81398E097D3656A4               179226  Using where
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     8   evotest.c.account   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   ref     IDX_6D28840D81398E09    IDX_6D28840D81398E09    9   evotest.c.id    1   Using where
```

So I tried to run this query in PhpMyAdmin, and the query executes in less than 1 second. Any idea why such a difference ? My web page executes a bunch of others queries, but this is the query which uses almost all of the total loading time.

**UPDATED QUERY :**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)) 
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN payment p ON p.customer = c.id 
WHERE p.init != 1 
AND p.cancel_date IS NULL 
AND p.unpaid != 1 
AND p.abo = 1 
AND p.value != 0 
AND c.date_next_payement > NOW()
```

This query is still very slow. Is there any way to optimize it ? I want to count the number of customers having at least 1 payment with given filters. the relation is on c.id = p.customer

Comment: Hi VaN, multiple joins have ruined more than one of my days! Have you tried using DQL/Doctrine instead? Perhaps it will be more optimized and will hopefully perform as expected since it's going through the DBAL.  Just a thought.

Comment: My first try was using DQL, but I thought there was no way DQL would be faster than pure SQL, as it's some kind of abstraction layer. So I switched to SQL. But I'll give a try again and see how fast it is.

Comment: Any chance this is MySQL query caching? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html

Comment: tried DQL, doesn't help. I updated my question with a new query where I removed 1 useless join. But it is still very slow. Any way to optimize this query ?

Comment: @PeterBailey this could be. I'm noticing some inconsistency from a page load to another. Sometimes, the query executes in 8 seconds (which is already very slow), sometimes in more than 25 seconds.

Comment: The two main causes of slow queries are 1) JOINs and 2) insufficient indexes on WHERE clauses. Since you've only got one JOIN, I'm going to suspect that one-or-more of your WHERE clauses doesn't have an index and is having to do a full table scan. If this query is going to execute a lot, you might benefit from creating a single index based on all 5 columns in `payment` that are in this WHERE clause.

Comment: @PeterBailey I just checked table structure, and as u suspected, they are no indexes on these fields. I'll add them and see. What the difference between creating a single index based on all 5 columns and creating 1 index on each column ? I'm also running queries with filters on only 2 or 3 of these 5 fields. Should I prefer indexing each field individually then ?

Comment: Fine-tuning DB indexes is a bit of an art - and one I can admit I'm not great at. I think it would be worthwhile for you to do independent research on the topic (e.g., try it both ways and measure the results) or re-ask that as a brand new question here on SO.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. i wish u had posted as an answer so I would have accept it. I can only upvote your previous comment dealing with indexes; which I did.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a subquery with `EXISTS` instead of a full join.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM customer c
WHERE c.date_next_payement > NOW()
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM payment p 
  WHERE p.customer = c.id 
  AND p.init != 1 
  AND p.cancel_date IS NULL 
  AND p.unpaid != 1 
  AND p.abo = 1 
  AND p.value != 0
);
```